# Problema con DataPicker e JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id;
    $(".cell").dblclick(function(e){
        id = e.target.id;
        $('#ModalReserva').modal('toggle'); 
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({date: id});

    });
});
```

Tengo varias celdas de una tabla, con la clase `cell`. Quiero que cuando se de doble clic, se me abra mi formulario modal. (hasta ahí bien), pero en el formulario modal tengo un `datapicker`.

Necesito que ese `datapicker` se establezca con el contenido del `id` de la celda que se le dio clic, todas las celdas de mi tabla tienen como `id` una fecha exacta como 10-12-2018 por ejemplo.

Cuando yo pongo `$('#datetimepicker1').Datetimepicker({date: id});` no me funciona, pero si hago `$('#datetimepicker1').Datetimepicker({date: '10-10-2018'});` entonces funciona correctamente.

¿Alguien sabe que pasa?

Comment: Probaste console.log para verificar lo que tiene e.target.id ?

Comment: Bueno, probe a hacer un alert(id) para ver que tenia dentro, y sale exactamente la fecha que tiene el id de la celda que se le dio clic.

O sea la fecha esta dentro del id, pero por alguna razon no me deja establecerla en el datapicker

Comment: Prueba hacer `var mydate = new Date(id);` y luego  `$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({date: mydate});`

Comment: Probé y nada, sigue sin coger la fecha. Es como si despues de construido el datapicker, ya no dejara ponerle ninguna fecha nueva.